# Rails Associations, Self Joins, fail to find the belong_to object on after_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationship within the same model.

From the belongs to object, Rails generate a wrong SQL to find the parent.

My model is as follow:

```
class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  enum kind: %i[main sized]
  has_many :sized_variants, -> { where kind: 'sized' }, :class_name => "Variant", :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  belongs_to :main_variant, -> { where kind: 'main' }, :class_name => "Variant", optional: true, :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  after_create :validate_main_variant

  def validate_main_variant
    if sized? && self.main_variant.nil?
      errors.add(:variant, 'main variant not found')
      throw :abort
    end
  end
```

In `after_create` of sized variant, when calling `self.main_variant` Rails generates the below SQL to find `main_variant` (foreign key parent_id) instead of just find by parent_id.

What is the mistake or possible solution here?

```
Variant Load (1.2ms)
SELECT  "variants".*
FROM "variants"
WHERE "variants"."product_id" = $1
AND "variants"."color_id" = $2
AND "variants"."size_id" = $3
AND "variants"."parent_id" = $4
AND "variants"."id" = $5
AND "variants"."kind" = $6
LIMIT $7
[["product_id", 20], ["color_id", 1], ["size_id", 1], ["parent_id", 44], ["id", 44], ["kind", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

I am using Rails 5.1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Extract from the rails way which is based on the rails documentation :

> 7.4.1.13 foreign_key: column_name Overrides the convention-based foreign key column name that would normally be used in the SQL
> statement that loads the association. Normally it would be the owning
> record’s class name with _id appended to it.
>
> 7.4.1.15 primary_key: column_name Specifies a surrogate key to use instead of the owning record’s primary key, whose value should be used
> when querying to fill the association collection.

What you did seems to tell Active Record how to bend its convention to retrieve a given `Variant` its owned associations but not how to retrieve a given `Variant` its owning association.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't get you. What I need is from a Variant object v with kind = 'sized', I want to call v.main_variant, to get select from Variant where variant.id = v.parent_id, why does the above code add all the other conditions?